# X-Tick Labels Are Not Getting Rotated! [How to Rotate X-Tick Labels in Seaborn Using Subplots & Figure]

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

```
f, ax  = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
g = sns.boxplot(x = 'YearBuilt', y = 'SalePrice', data = df_train)
g.set_xticklabels(g.get_xticklabels(), rotation=30)
```

I am trying to rotate the x labels but instead of rotating the x ticks, the code gets printed the whole x labels.
[x ticks list gets printed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfAtd.png)

How do I fix this issue!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved Using this Code:

```
f, ax  = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10))
g = sns.boxplot(x = 'YearBuilt', y = 'SalePrice', data = df_train)
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(),rotation=90, minor=False);
```

Comment: Well, the only real difference is the semicolon at the end that hides printing the result of the last function (`set_xticklabels` in this case).